# Insert ignore vs duplilcate key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to write a short php script that will select from a table on one server and insert/update into
a table on a different server. This is to keep our working production database up to date with everything in our
DB2 database so that we can preform all queries locally.

So my connections to both Databases are successful and my SELECT statement on the DB2 side is also successful. The 
only issue I'm running into is my INSERT/UPDATE procedure which I'm not getting errors on, as much as I don't
really know how I should go about this.

My initial idea was INSERT IGNORE, but I'm wondering if it should be On DUPLICATE KEY.....UPDATE.

Basically, I dumped the DB2 table the other day and imported into mysql, now I just need to keep it constantly updated. Both tables
have about 15000 records, sot there's a lot to go through. I just need to look at everything in DB2 and if there's
a brand new record, insert it, or if it's obivous that a phone or email has been updated in DB2, I want to update
it on the mysql side.

The records can have company number 1-5 associated with each customer number, which may come into play with updating
on duplicate, but I'm still unsure of the best way to go about this.

Any tips on the best way to do what I need here?

```
//Query for selecting records from  DB2

$query1 = "select xcompn, xcstno, xbllnm, xcntpc, xcntec from jacmfg.custmstf";
$prep1 = odbc_prepare($DB2Conn, $query1);
$exec1 = odbc_execute($prep1);

//If either query fails
if (!$exec1) {

  die('Could not update.');
}
else {
echo 'success';
}

 //Query for inserting and updating on mysql 


$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqlConn, 
    "INSERT ignore into ambition.ambition_customer_data(companyNumber, customerNumber, businessName,
    phone, email )
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
      ON duplicate key update
      -- unfinished statement
          ") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));
```

Comment: You should use just Insert instead of Insert ignore. Insert statement should be INSERT into ambition.ambition_customer_data(companyNumber, customerNumber, businessName,
    phone, email )
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON duplicate key update companyNumber = values(companyNumber), customerNumber = values(customerNumber), businessName= values(businessName), phone = values(phone), email = values(email)

Comment: Ok so if I do that, and make a unique index on the table, should the index be on the company number and customer number, or should the index be on every field so that something only gets updated if there's already a record where everything else is the same?

Comment: Unique index should be on Company Number and Customer Number.